# How to protect rating system written with GAE usage (i.e. allow only one vote)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When my site is loaded, I get unique user's id. User can not change it - the site is loaded as iframe and id is passed thru GET:

```
if self.request.get('user_id'):
     user = User(key_name="id"+self.request.get('viewer_id'))
     user.put()
```

It can be used to allow only one vote per one user id. But how can I pass it safely to another GAE page? I.e. user loaded my first page, I've save his/her id to the datastore (`User` model). User will vote on another page - I can not pass his id as `?id=12345` to another page. What should I do to know this id at another page (so that user will not be able to change that)?

Answer (score 1):

This mechanism isn't safe in the first place - a user could easily look at the iframe in his browser, determine how the ID is passed in, and change it to pass in any ID they wish. You need to work out a way of getting the user ID from the host site that is actually secure.

As to ensuring users can't imitate each other after that, you should use a sessions library to establish a cookie session, and store the user's ID in the session state.

Comment: OK, I found the way to verify user_id at the first page (3rd party site provides me with additional verification parameters). Could you please provide me with more details about second part of your answer? Can I generate some uuid at the first page and assign it to this user (in my datastore), save that to the cookies and use at each page after that?

Comment: @LA_ Use an existing session library, like Beaker (presuming you're using Python; you don't say) rather than inventing your own.